# Angular-4 d3 v4 Issue: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'HierarchyNode'

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to create a d3 tree in my angular app, i am trying this example:
https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/08ecb6ea9bb68ba0d9a7e89f344acec8

Problem exists when trying to access the nodes x-y coordinates, i get the error:
Property 'x' does not exist on type 'HierarchyNode'

When I log the data, i could see that the x-y coordinates are there.
[Screenshot showing the logged data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIzfX.png)

```js
  // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
  var treemap = d3.tree()
    .size([this.height, this.width]);

  //  assigns the data to a hierarchy using parent-child relationships
  var nodes = d3.hierarchy(this.treeData, function(d) {
    return d.children;
    });
  // maps the node data to the tree layout
  nodes = treemap(nodes);
console.log(nodes.descendants());
  // adds each node as a group
  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) { 
      return "node" + 
        (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

the d.x & d.y produce the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript has [contextual type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html), and since HierarchyNode doesn't export 'x' and 'y' properties this wouldn't compile. You can use 'any' as the input type to avoid the error:

```
...
.attr("transform", function(d: any) { 
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specify the type to override [Contextual Typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing)

```
.attr('cx', function (d: HierarchyPointNode<MyDatumInterface>) {
        return d.x // no TS error
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. Although zokar.com's answer fixes it, it breaks the type checking. The problem arises from the fact that after treemap(root), the nodes in the tree are added with x and y properties. They should be typed as HierarchyPointNode rather than HierarchyNode. But treemap does not convert the types properly. You can use type assertion to correct it:

```
interface NodeCustom{
        ...
      }
const root = d3.hierarchy<NodeCustom>(YourTreeData as NodeCustom)
...
treemap(root)
const nodes = (root.descendants() as HierarchyPointNode<NodeCustom>[])
```